# Natural translation of 숨을 곳도 찾지 못해 나는

Tags: grammar, translation

> **숨을 곳도 찾지 못해 나는** 피하려고 애써 봐도
>
> 거부조차 할 수 없는 네게 갇혀버린 나

These are the opening lines of [Shinee's *Lucifer*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dww9UjJ4Dt8).

What would be a natural way to precisely translate this phrase? Something like "I, who can't find even a place to hide'?

Does '숨을 곳도 찾지 못해' become an adjectival phrase? Does it mean the same as '숨을 곳도 찾지 못하는'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to provide a formal answer, but as a native speaker, I feel that

> 숨을 곳도 찾지 못해 나...

translates to

> Not even being able to find a place to hide, I...

or

> Also not being able to find a place to hide, I...

depending on the context behind the 도.

Meanwhile,

> 숨을 곳도 찾지 못하는 나

translates to a form that puts more dramatic emphasis on the "I," as if the first words were a preamble to the "I":

> I, who couldn't even find a place to hide, ...

or

> I, who also couldn't find a place to hide, ...

I believe this is what you're referring to as an adjectival phrase. If so, no, the first form isn't an adjectival phrase—it's a separate clause—but the latter is indeed an adjectival phrase.

Comment: Note that "Not even being able to find a place to hide, I..." can be made "natural" into "I cannot even find a place to hide"

Comment: @busukxuan not quite - because the "I..." from his translation is the subject of the *following* clause: 나는 피하려고 애써 봐도

Comment: @dotVezz that's what I thought, but according to the OP's and this answer's interpretation putting these two together, it could perhaps be interpreted this way.

Comment: @busukxuan Unfortunately no, translating it that way does *significantly* change its meaning.